# Access PHP files without typing extension but also allow folders default to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess`:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To my limited understanding of Apache htaccess rules this is doing two things:

1. Redirecting `http://` to `https://`
2. Allow access of `domain.com/file.php` files as `domain.com/file`

The problem is that rule #2 thinks every call to anything `/name` is a `name.php` when sometimes is an actual folder, and I need it to redirect to that folder's `index.php` file by default.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to skip rewriting real directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=307,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]

## Redirect to HTTPS. Remove if you do not want this.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

## Disables indexing (Always a good idea :D)
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I forgot to specify I wanted to keep/add the `www.` in the displayed URL address, can you help me with that?

Comment: Hello! The last rewrite rule should force www at the beginning. If it's not, you may have another script preventing it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line and try replacing with:

```
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `%{REQUEST_FILENAME }` exists as an existing php file before rewriting it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https: //%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```